# Sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\mathcal{F} \otimes\mathcal{G} \cong \mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n}$: what are they called?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

If $X$ is a scheme then the Picard group of $X$ is the collection of invertible sheaves, so the collection of those sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ such that there's an $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ satisfying $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{F}^{-1} \cong \mathcal{O}_X$. I'm interested in the larger group of those sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ such that there's a $\mathcal{G}$ satisfying $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{G} \cong \mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n}$ for some $n$. Does this have a name?